# Python's JSON Format (with flask) format

Tags: python, json, flask

Ruby on Rails JSON is able to parse out curl calls in the following format:

`name=test`. It will interpret this as `{"name": "test"}`.

Python's `JSON` seems to take this as a JSON error (which it obviously is). Is there a way however, to take parse payload in the format of `name=test`? I'm using Python's `JSON` with Flask here.

Comment: This [function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to parse query strings might be useful perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using flask, why not use jsonify

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/do')
def do_whatever():
    return jsonify(name=test)
```

This will send a JSON response like this to the browser:

```
{
    "name": "test",
}
```

Comment: This is useful, thanks but I want to modify the attributes first and then return them in a JSON format. This seems to return a response object. `name=test` is passed as payload/data via curl. How can I parse that data as `"name":"test"`, or a json/dict??

Comment: Here's an example of a curl call: `curl -X POST http://localhost:5000 -d name=somename -d age=15`. I've done this in Rails before, but not sure how to in Flask.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
fields = curl_str.split('=')
curl_json = { fields[0]:fields[1] }
```

Comment: What if my request contained:
`curl .... -d name=test -d age=12 -d location=somecity`? This won't parse out all the data, will it?